# Require instant MFA for specific Action in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0, multi-factor-authentication

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6. The app is configured to consume Azure AD authentication with MFA:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

The enterprise application is configured to require MFA every now and then. However, I'd like to have the app require additional authentication for sensitive actions, e.g. password reset in the profile.

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    if (User.Identity is not { IsAuthenticated: true })
        return Forbid();

    // ask for another token from MFA

    User.ChangePassword();
}
```

Is this to be configured in the enterprise application or can I trigger that somehow from code?

Comment: Cant you just add a custom attribute and call some azure function to force mfa?

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not fully work, however I managed to reauthenticate the user with this solution. Hopefully I find a working way.

Basically, I followed this article: https://hajekj.net/2017/03/06/forcing-reauthentication-with-azure-ad/

Add this in program.cs Main:

```
builder.Services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
            {
                if (ShouldReauthenticate(context))
                {
                    //context.ProtocolMessage.MaxAge = "0"; //fully authenticate user with password -> THIS DOES WORK
                    context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("amr_values", "ngcmfa"); //ask for mfa again -> THIS DOESN'T
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            };
        });
```

Add this to program.cs Program class:

```
internal static bool ShouldReauthenticate(RedirectContext context)
{
    context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("reauthenticate", out string reauthenticate);

    bool shouldReauthenticate = false;
    if (reauthenticate != null && !bool.TryParse(reauthenticate, out shouldReauthenticate))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{reauthenticate}' is an invalid boolean value");
    }

    return shouldReauthenticate;
}
```

Create RequireReauthenticationAttribute class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;

namespace Classes;

public class RequireReauthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    private readonly int _secondsElapsedSinceLast;
    public RequireReauthenticationAttribute(int secondsElapsedSinceLast)
    {
        _secondsElapsedSinceLast = secondsElapsedSinceLast;
    }
    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        bool foundAuthTime = int.TryParse(context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("auth_time")?.Value, out int authTime);

        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        long currentUnixTime = ((DateTimeOffset)currentTime).ToUnixTimeSeconds();

        long secondsPassed = currentUnixTime - authTime;

        if (foundAuthTime && secondsPassed < _secondsElapsedSinceLast)
        {
            await next();
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> state = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "reauthenticate", "true" } };
            await context.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties(state)
            {
                RedirectUri = context.HttpContext.Request.Path
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Add this to Razor Page, Controller or Controller action:

```
[RequireReauthentication(1)] //force reauth after 1 second, for testing
```

In Azure AD Portal configure the Enterprise Application and add optional claim "auth_time" (ID and Access) in Token Configuration.

This method works for reauthenticating a user with password (THIS DOES WORK), it doesn't work for just MFA (THIS DOESN'T).

When asking for mfa only the error message is:

> AADSTS901002: The 'amr_values' request parameter is not supported.